# Split Row Value in Datagrid at custom character

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid

In a GWT Datagrid the content of a row is splitted into seperate parts if the row is to small to show the complete value. But this only happens if the value of the row contains a whitespace.
Is it possible to enable this behavior for other characters like an underscore.
Background is that i have to show long names of parts which do not contain any whitespaces, but only underscores.[image]

To illustrate my problem i made the following example. The first three rows contain whitespaces and are distributed each on two rows. But the last column is just shown incomplete.

If possible i would avoid to replace some of the underscores which whitespaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to apply the following CSS rule to your cell:

```
word-break: break-all;
```

This will force the long words to break, but not necessarily at the underscore character. This, however, may be acceptable for part numbers.

The other solution requires you to process all words before you display them by inserting a `<wbr>` tag after each underscore - you can do it in the `getValue` method of your cell. This solution will work in HTML5-enabled browsers.

Comment: I overrode the getCellStyleNames and referd to a css class with "word-break: break-all;" in it. But nothing happens? I also checked the cell with the firefox debug tool and the word-break snippet was applied

Comment: Okay i found the problem : The columnWidth was too big and the part was not splitted.